# How do you make prediction for new observations with sklearn model?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, spam-prevention, supervised-learning, countvectorizer

So, this feels like a dumb question, but I can't figure out how to actually use the text-based Machine Learning predictor that I have created.

I used multiple YouTube videos to brush up on Supervised Machine Learning to make predictions from text. Most videos used the classic Ham or Spam predictor for filtering out spam emails or text messages, and I coded along and seemingly succeeded at what the video was trying to teach me.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=37)

cvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

X_train_cvec = cvec.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_cvec = cvec.transform(X_test)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train_cvec, y_train)

print(f'Training Score for CountVectorizer: {lr.score(X_train_cvec, y_train)}')
print(f'Testing Score for CountVectorizer: {lr.score(X_test_cvec, y_test)}')

Training Score for CountVectorizer: 0.9961857751851021
Testing Score for CountVectorizer: 0.9865470852017937
```

But after the video ended, I realized I have no idea how to actually implement this. In none of these videos did they actually show me how to test the this on data where I don't know what the answer is in advance, and for the life of me I can't figure it out.

To clarify what I mean, I want to be able to put in text like 'how u doin' and 'CONGRATULATION you have just been chosen for blah blah blah' and see if the predictor I have created can predict is these are Ham (0) or Spam (1).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to pass new data to the `predict` function of your model while applying all the transformation that you have used during the training.

In this case:

```py
lr.predict(cvec.transform(X_new))
```

where `X_new` contains new observations.

Comment: As irritatingly simple as I expected. Thank you.